# Xcode 7 - Incompatible block pointer types

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

This code worked fine in Xcode 6, but now won't compile in Xcode 7.
Any ideas how to fix and why this is an issue in Xcode 7?

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(SKSpriteNode *__strong, NSUInteger, BOOL *)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(SKNode * _Nonnull __strong, NSUInteger, BOOL * _Nonnull)'

```
[self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKSpriteNode * node, NSUInteger idx,BOOL *stop)
{
    float parallaxRatio = [(NSNumber *)node.userData[@"ParallaxRatio"] floatValue];
    CGPoint childVelocity = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, parallaxRatio);
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMultiplyScalar(childVelocity, deltaTime);
    node.position = CGPointAdd(node.position, offset);
}];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several interfaces seem to have changed with iOS9 / Xcode7. In that case you most easily fix it, by typing `[self.children enum`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and select the appropriate method from the list. This will give you a code fragment with the new block pointer type and you can move the code in there.

The result would be this: (`node` was `obj` after autocompletion, I just renamed it)

```
[self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKNode * _Nonnull node, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) 
{
    float parallaxRatio = [(NSNumber *)node.userData[@"ParallaxRatio"] floatValue];
    CGPoint childVelocity = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, parallaxRatio);
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMultiplyScalar(childVelocity, deltaTime);
    node.position = CGPointAdd(node.position, offset);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, compiles now!