# Use of undeclared identifier 'child'

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

This code worked fined prior to Xcode 7, but now its throwing error .

I tried to use the solution at [XCode7 - Incompatible block pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724880/xcode7-incompatible-block-pointer-types) but its still giving error

**Property 'size' not found on object of type 'SKNode *'**

```
    -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKNode * _Nonnull child, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
     {
         child.position = CGPointMake(child.position.x-self.scrollingSpeed, child.position.y);
         if (child.position.x <= -child.size.width){
             float delta = child.position.x+child.size.width;
             child.position = CGPointMake(child.size.width*(self.children.count-1)+delta, child.position.y);
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the complete and exact error message.

Comment: @rmaddy done updated with exact error

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, it was easy to spot just write the code again it gives you the new auto suggested stuff

```
[self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKSpriteNode*  _Nonnull child, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
  if (child.position.x <= -child.size.width){
    float delta = child.position.x+child.size.width;
    child.position = CGPointMake(child.size.width*(self.children.count-1)+delta, child.position.y);
  }
}];
```

Comment: it still throws the same error Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(SKSpriteNode * _Nonnull __strong, NSUInteger, BOOL * _Nonnull)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(SKNode * _Nonnull __strong, NSUInteger, BOOL * _Nonnull)'

Comment: You have changed the variable name from `child` to `node` please correct it, also you have changed it type from `SKSpriteNode` to `SKNode`. Please be sure what you want to do

Comment: thanks, now it throws following error Property 'size' not found on object of type 'SKNode *'